# Selecting the last used cell in column A and then extend it to column H

Tags: vba, excel

Hi there I am trying to select  a range `"A2:H2"` down to the last filled cell based on `column A` (so in this case it should select `"A2:H59"`). The range is not fixed so it cannot be defined with exact numbers. I have the following code, but it selects everything down to the 402nd row even though there is no data beyond `"A59"` in the sheet. Any idea what is going on? Thanks for the help!

```
Global ssaw As Worksheet
Global trckr As Worksheet
Sub DataF()
Dim myRange As Range
Dim myCell As Range

    Set ssaw = Sheets("SSAW_DATA")
    Set trckr = Sheets("SQL_DATA_FEED")
    Set myRange = trckr.Range("A2:H2").end(xlDown)


        With myRange
            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 102, 102)
            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Value = "#missing#"
        End With

End Sub
```

Comment: What do you get when you use `Set LastCellA = trckr.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)`?

Comment: try select A2 in the spreadsheet and press Ctrl+ArrowDown. What happened?

Comment: there's something in those cells, maybe a space, etc.  Select the first blank row, down to Row 402, then hit the Delete button on your keyboard, then try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we assume your last used cell in column A is `A59` then …

… This

```
Set myRange = trckr.Range("A2", trckr.Range("A2").End(xlDown))
```

will select `A2:A59` and this

```
.Resize(ColumnSize:=8)
```

will resize it to make it 8 columns width that is `A2:H59`.

So together we get:

```
Set myRange = trckr.Range("A2", trckr.Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Resize(ColumnSize:=8)
```

---

Use this

```
trckr.Range("A" & trckr.Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
```

alternatively to find the last used cell in column A if there can be empty cells in between:

```
Set myRange = trckr.Range("A2", trckr.Range("A" & trckr.Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Resize(ColumnSize:=8)
```

Comment: Yep this one worked wonders, thanks :) No odd 402 row selections here!

Answer (score 2):

exploit the fact that `Range(cell1, cell2)` is equivalent to `Range(cell2, cell1)`

```
Set myRange = trckr.Range("H2", trckr.Range("A2").End(xlDown))
```

while if you want to select a range from A2:H2 down to column A last not empty cell (i.e. included empty cells along column A in between the first and last not empty ones):

```
Set myRange = trckr.Range("H2", trckr.Cells(trckr.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
```

Comment: Nice one, I really like that one. You need to think around the corner so using `Resize` might be more convenient, but that definitely got my points.

Comment: Interesting approach, still trying to wrap my head around it haha.

Comment: @Rhyfelwr, well  it can boil down to "a rectangle can be identified by any two opposite corners of it"

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use the following code

```
Option Explicit

Function LastRowInColumn(colName As String)
    Dim lastRow As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, colName).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    LastRowInColumn = lastRow
End Function


Sub SelectRg()
Dim rg As Range
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long

    lastRow = LastRowInColumn("A")
    Debug.Print lastRow

    If lastRow = 1 Then
        ' do nothing
    Else
        Set wks = ActiveSheet
        With wks
            Set rg = Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(lastRow, "H"))
            rg.Select
        End With
    End If

End Sub
```

The code determins the last filled row in column A and select based on this information everything to column H

**EDIT** Improved function

```
Function LastRowInColumn(ByVal wks As Worksheet, ByVal colName As String) As Long
    With wks
        LastRowInColumn = .Cells(.Rows.Count, colName).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
End Function
```

**EDIT2** And if one would not like to use an extra function you could do it like that

```
Sub SetRg()

Dim rg As Range
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long

    Set wks = ActiveSheet
    With wks
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        'lastRow = LastRowInColumn(wks, "A")
        If lastRow > 1 Then
            Set rg = Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(lastRow, "H"))
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, your version works too, I am just trying to keep it simple.

Comment: You suggest 20 lines of code where 1 line is enough to solve it? You really should re-think if that is a good idea.

Comment: You think your code is more readable than `Set myRange = trckr.range(trckr.range("A2").End(xlDown), "H2")`? If "more" is related to its length then yes.

Comment: First of all your code is not complete unless you prefer not to dim variables etc. And I think to have a function for determing the last filled cell in a row follows the principle of reusabiltiy. Anyway, you can do it as you want to do it and I can do it as I want. So, where is the problem?

Comment: OK, let me have 2 more lines for the variable declaration then and 2 more for the `Sub`/`End Sub`. Anyway I didn't want say it is not possible to do it that way you did (and of course you can), just asking if this really is a good idea.

Comment: Just a couple of pointers, I don't think you need a `Function` to get last row. It's just a single line statement that can be used in your main `Sub` (in this case `SelectRg`). More concerning is the use of `ActiveSheet`. I see so many queries here because of unqualified sheets. Problem with using `ActiveSheet` is that it may or may not be the sheet that you want to interact with. I would suggest qualifying your sheets. Use of `With` is a great approach because then you don't need to qualify the sheet in an object. You can directly reference it in `With` statement. Hope it makes sense

Comment: Yes, right, I was just too hasty. I edited the function accordingly